# SQL create a full part list out of a given part list (iteration)

Tags: sql, postgresql, iteration

I have a problem with a given task from my SQL lecture.
In the task there is a database given with a list of parts of three robots and another list, where these parts are linked to parts from the first list, that they are made of, if they are made of other parts.

The databasess can be generated with:

```
CREATE TABLE part (
part_id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
part_namevarchar(64)NOTNULL
);

CREATE TABLE part_part (
    object_id BIGINT,
    part_id BIGINT,
    quantity INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(object_id, part_id)
);
ALTER TABLE part_part
 ADD CONSTRAINT part_id_fkey FOREIGNKEY (part_id) REFERENCES part(part_id)
 ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;

 ALTER TABLE part_part
 ADD CONSTRAINT object_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY(object_id)REFERENCES part(part_id)
 ON UPDATE CASCADE ONDELETE CASCADE;

 INSERT INTO part(part_id, part_name)
 VALUES
 (0,'CPU A'),
 (1,'Cables'),
 (2,'Motherboard 3xy'),
 (3,'Motor ayX'),
 (4,'Arm'),
 (5,'Body'),
 (6,'Leg'),
 (7,'Wheel'),
 (8,'Motherboard 7ax'),
 (9,'Joint'),
 (10,'Motor Z1238'),
 (11,'Hammer'),
 (12,'Screw A'),
 (13,'Screw B'),
 (14,'Screw C'),
 (15,'Robo 1000'),
 (16,'CPU B'),
 (17,'CPU C'),
 (18,'Robo 2000'),
 (19,'Screwdriver'),
 (20,'Robo 3000');

 INSERT INTO part_part
 (object_id, part_id, quantity)
 VALUES
 (5,2,1),
 (5,0,1),
 (5,3,2),
 (5,1,5),
 (5,12,3),
 (4,9,3),
 (4,10,3),
 (4,13,13),
 (6,3,2),
 (6,7,4),
 (15,4,2),
 (15,11,2),
 (15,5,1),
 (15,6,1),
 (18,4,2),
 (18,11,2),
 (18,5,1),
 (18,6,2),
 (18,16,1),
 (20,4,3),
 (20,11,1),
 (20,19,1),
 (20,5,1),
 (20,6,1),
 (20,16,1),
 (20,17,1);
```

Now the task is to get the list of all parts and subparts needed for the "Robo 3000" and their quantity.

I got as far as:

```
WITH part2(part_name1, subpart_id, top_quantity, top_part_id, part_name) AS(
  WITH part1(part_name, subpart_id, quantity) AS(
  WITH subpart1(object_id, subpart_id, quantity) AS(SELECT * FROM part_part)
  SELECT part_name, subpart_id, quantity FROM subpart1
    JOIN part ON part.part_id = subpart1.object_id
     WHERE part_name = 'Robo 3000'
  )
  SELECT * FROM part1
  JOIN part ON part1.subpart_id = part.part_id
)
SELECT * FROM part2
JOIN part_part ON part2.top_part_id = part_part.object_id
ORDER BY top_part_id;
```

Which gives me a list of only subparts (the parts of all the parts from the robot, that need parts themselves) and also it doesn't consider, if parts are used multiple times, here the arm is used 3 times but its parts aren't multiplied with the quantity.

Also this is limited, since it only looks at the given part and the supp parts but not deeper if needed.

Is there a way to iterate through all the parts and make them into a big list in SQL?

The same way for example a java method would with a self calling method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL supports [recursive sQL](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-recursive-query/) which may be one way solve your problem. Below is a example using your data.

```
with recursive part_list as
(
    (
    select object_id as unit, object_id, part_id, quantity, quantity as totqty 
      from  part_part 
     where object_id = 20
    )
    union
    select pl.unit, pp.object_id, pp.part_id, pp.quantity, pp.quantity * pl.quantity
      from part_part pp 
      join part_list pl
        on pp.object_id = pl.part_id
)
select u.part_name as unit,
        part.part_name, 
        sum(part_list.totqty) as total_parts
  from part_list
  join part u
    on u.part_id = part_list.unit
  join part 
    on part.part_id = part_list.part_id
group by u.part_name, part.part_name    
order by 1,3;
```